# All transactions sent are duplicated

Tags: web3js, metamask, 0x

As the title says, every transaction I send through the window.ethereum object injected by metamask is duplicated. Currently I am trying to send one transaction to set the token allowance for a swap and then one to perform the swap. Under both instances metamask prompts the user to approve 4 transactions (two of each of the ones I am trying to perform). I've narrowed it down to being the web3 methods, as when I paste the methods twice I'll end up getting eight transactions. Could anyone help me with this issue?

```
  async function swap() {
    const web3access = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    const abi = [{ "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "name", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "symbol", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "max_supply", "type": "uint256" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "Approval", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" } ], "name": "allowance", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "approve", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "account", "type": "address" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "burn", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "account", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "burnFrom", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "decimals", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "", "type": "uint8" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "subtractedValue", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "decreaseAllowance", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "addedValue", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "increaseAllowance", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "sender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }];
    const maxApproval = "10000000000000000000000000000000000"; 
    console.log(maxApproval);
    const contract = new web3access.eth.Contract(abi, sellToken);
    const account = await accountPromise;
    let allowanceQuote = await getQuote(true);
    let swapQuote = await getQuote(false);
    allowanceQuote.onreadystatechange = (e) => { //Maybe should check if user has already set approval for sellToken passed in above depending on whether or not I decide to have users set unlimited token allowances per token approval.
        let responseDict = JSON.parse(allowanceQuote.responseText)
        contract.methods.approve(responseDict["allowanceTarget"], maxApproval).send({from: account}).then(tx => { //Token approval method for 0x api contract address
        console.log(tx);
        });
    };
    swapQuote.onreadystatechange = (e) => { //Need this to run AFTER a response from the above approve method returns a successful transaction.
        let responseDict = JSON.parse(swapQuote.responseText)
        console.log(web3access.eth.sendTransaction(responseDict));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `accountPromise`, `getQuote`? Can you share the logged output?

Comment: The account promise is the promise object that delivers the public key of the user. The getQuote method retrieves the quote from the 0x API to be used for the transaction.